# amazon ses with Amazon EC2 website: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to use Amazon SES on a Amazon EC2 linux server. I tried everything, I am already follow all the tutorials but I cant use the SMTP from my Amazon SES on my application.

the error:
  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
  SMTP Error Message: SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-222567251
  SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok
  SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
  SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Ok
  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use telnet to establish a connection?

This thread has a bunch of suggestions:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=301767

### From about 2/3 down that thread:

The terminology around SSL and TLS is sometimes used in inconsistent or confusing ways in third-party documentation. I believe the problem you encountered is related to the feature set of those libraries rather than a difference between the way SSL and TLS work. Two different ways of establishing secure connections include STARTTLS and the Handshake Protocol.

STARTTLS provides a way for text protocols (SMTP, IMAP, POP3, etc.) to negotiate a secure connection using TLS/SSL within an existing established plaintext connection.

The Handshake Protocol (aka wrapper mode) supports the establishment of TLS/SSL connections which are secured before the application protocol begins. The Amazon SES SMTP interface currently requires the Handshake Protocol and does not support STARTTLS. We support both SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0.

The SSL and TLS specifications are a good source of further information about the Handshake Protocol:
 •SSL 3.0 specification (RFC 6101)
 •TLS 1.0 specification (RFC 2246)
 The documentation of Net::SMTP::SSL claims it supports the handshake protocol with SSL, while Net::SMTP::TLS suggests that it supports only STARTTLS not the TLS handshake protocol. I believe the library's lack of support for the handshake protocol explains why it did not work for you.

Comment: TL;DR: Use SSL not TLS for ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server.